# switchMap combined with mergeMap

Tags: typescript, rxjs, switchmap, mergemap

I have an Observable where each new value should cause an HTTP request. On the client-side I only care about the latest response value; however, I want every request to complete for monitoring/etc. purposes.

What I currently have is something like:

```
function simulate(x) {
  // Simulate an HTTP request.
  return of(x).pipe(delay(6));
}

source$.pipe(
  someMapFunc(x => simulate(x)),
);
```

When I use `switchMap` for the `someMapFunc`, I get the right set of responses (only the latest). However, if the request is taking too long, it will get canceled.

When I use `mergeMap` instead, I get the right set of requests (every request completes), but I get the wrong set of responses (every single one).

[image: marble diagram of code above]

**Is there a way to get the requests of `mergeMap` with the responses of `switchMap`?** I know I can write this as a custom operator, but I'm wondering if I can build this out of existing/standard rxjs operators. To summarize what I'm thinking of:

- a version of `switchMap` that doesn't unsubscribe when it switches;
- a version of `mergeMap` that only emits values from the latest inner Observable.

**Edit**: Based on the accepted answer, I was able to get the following, which works:

```
function orderedMergeMap(project) {
  return (s) => defer(() => {
    let recent = 0;
    return s.pipe(
      mergeMap((data, idx) => {
        recent = idx;
        return project(data).pipe(filter(() => idx === recent));
      })
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're after, and I haven't fully tested this, but I created a custom operator that might do something close to what you're after. Maybe you can tinker with it a bit more.

This is a mergeMap that filters out "old" values. Old values are emissions from sources that happen after a newer source starts to emit.

```ts
function orderedMergeMap<T, R>(project: (v:T) => Observable<R>): OperatorFunction<T, R> {
  return s => defer(() => {
    let recent = 0;
    return s.pipe(
      map((v, i) => ({order: i, payload: v})),
      mergeMap(({order, payload}) => project(payload).pipe(
        map(v => ({order, payload: v}))
      )),
      tap(({order}) => {
        if(order > recent) recent = order;
      }),
      filter(({order}) => order < recent),
      map(({payload}) => payload)
    );
  });
}
```

The version OP settled on:

```ts
function orderedMergeMap<T, R>(project: (v:T) => Observable<R>): OperatorFunction<T, R> {
  return s => defer(() => { 
    let recent = 0; 
    return s.pipe( 
      mergeMap((data, idx) => { 
        recent = idx; 
        return project(data).pipe(
          filter(() => idx === recent)
        ); 
      }) 
    ); 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I could not get your version working, but I was able to build something out of it:

`
function orderedMergeMap(project) {
  return (s) => defer(() => {
    let recent = 0;
    return s.pipe(
      mergeMap((data, idx) => {
        recent = idx;
        return project(data).pipe(filter(() => idx === recent));
      })
    );
  });
}
`

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you need a combination of `concatMap()` and `last()`.

`concatMap` does not subscribe to the next observable until the previous completes. Using it you will ensure the order of requests execution. And as it follows from the description it doesn't cancel previous subscriptions and let them finish, unlike `switchMap`.

`last` emits the last value emitted from the source on completion. Using it you will ensure that only one (last) result will be passed to the result.

Your code will look like that:

```
source$.pipe(
  concatMap(x => simulate(x)),
  last()
);
```

Comment: The `last` operator cannot be used in this context. It propagates only last element on the completion of the source observable.